# Set Location Center of Map - GMaps v2 - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

How do I set the center of the map to a specific location using GMaps v2?  This is how I did it using GMaps v1:

```
public void setCenter( LatLng point )
{
  if( point.latitude*1000000 != 0 && point.longitude*1000000 != 0 )
  {
     if( mMapController != null )
     {
        mMapController.setCenter( point );
     }
     /*else if( mOpenStreetMapViewControllerSource != null )
     {
        mOpenStreetMapViewControllerSource.getController().setCenter( new org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint( point.getLatitudeE6(), point.getLongitudeE6() ) );
        mPostponedSetCenterPoint = point;
     }*/
  }
}
```

I have looked through the API for GMaps v2 and can't find and similar functionality.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom));
```

where `map` is the GoogleMap instance.

Comment: I try this but doesnt really look centered... any ideas to get it exactly on center or my eyes are failing? (i am using animateCamera)

Comment: Oh don't worry, there was nothing to fix. The GPS off and some wrong code made it behave weirdly. the code you show does put it exactly centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(SYDNEY));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 4.0f));
}
```